# Subquery in Linq query giving A query body must end with a select clause or a group clause

Tags: c#, linq

booked - below - should be the sum of the NumberBooked column from the Bookings table - which has a link to the TourDates table on the TourDateId.

However I'm getting the error `A query body must end with a select clause or a group clause`

Can anyone please help me fix this query?

Thank you,

Mark

```
var tours  = from t in Tours
   join d in TourDates on t.TourId equals d.TourId
   where d.Date == dt
      select new
        {
           t.TourId,
           d.TourDateId,
           booked = (from b in Bookings where d.TourDateId == b.TourDateId) 
                     Select new {bk.Sum(b.NumberBooked()} 
       };
```

Comment: Shouldn't that last "Select" start with a lowercase 'S'...?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The closing round paranthesis ends the query which needs a `select` at the end.

Why don't you use method syntax? It is much better readable in this case. Also,  a `Select` is optional with `.Where` and method syntax:

```
  join d in TourDates on t.TourId equals d.TourId
  where d.Date == dt
  select new
  {
       t.TourId,
       d.TourDateId,
       booked = Bookings.Where(b => d.TourDateId == b.TourDateId)
                        .Sum(b => b.NumberBooked()) 
  };
```

Note that i have removed the anonymous type since you just want the sum of that column

> should be the sum of the NumberBooked column from the Bookings table -
>   which has a link to the TourDates table on the TourDateId.

Answer (score 2):

I believe this:

```
booked = (from b in Bookings where d.TourDateId == b.TourDateId) // oops
                 Select new {bk.Sum(b.NumberBooked()}
```

should be this:

```
booked = (from b in Bookings where d.TourDateId == b.TourDateId // move from here
                 select new {bk.Sum(b.NumberBooked()}) // to here
```

Note that I moved the end parenthesis `)` so that it comes after the select, not after `TourDateId`